# Bootstrap two inputs in input-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following HTML, but I can't get two inputs to be on same line as all buttons.

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Page path"> 
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> 
        <div class="input-group-btn">                           
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View</a> 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/Iu7Ic99jm6

Comment: You're kinda abusing the input-group widget. Good luck with that. "We do not support multiple add-ons on a single side. We do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group." – http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap makes the width of those input elements 100%. You will need to overwrite that value. Something like this:

```
.input-group .form-control {
  width:45%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
```

See my bootply fork here:
http://www.bootply.com/ApJNHnX5Lv

Comment: This will inflict on all other use of `.form-control` etc throughout the application. Why not use the markup as it is intended to be used in bootstrap, instead of changing the responsive css layout?

Comment: @davidkonrad It would be trivial to make the rule more specific by adding a class. I agree your answer is also good but the result is different. I tried with my answer to give an insight of what was actually happening in the OPs CSS to behave the way it was.

Comment: Hey @ElwoodP, yes, just saying :) And it doesnt matter if you are not using `.form-control` etc elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Place the entire content in a `.form-inline` `<form>` tag, and place the input and button sections in `.form-group` `<div>`'s :

```
<div class="well">
      <form class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-medium" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Page path"> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-medium" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name"> 
         </div>  
         <div class="form-group">                           
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View</a> 
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
         </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

see forked bootply -> **http://www.bootply.com/xSxTb0xzqh**

Answer (score 1):

Try using class `form-inline`

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Page path"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name"> 
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View</a> 
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> 
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IK9wgOh9lr)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `col` divs to force the inputs to be in certain places. in combo with  `form-inline` / `form-group` [like so](http://www.bootply.com/ZzWGFdHPC9)